# django tastypie filter a non orm field

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I am trying to create a webservice in django tastypie . In my model, I have

```
class Temp((models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    @property
    def modelNumber(self):  
        return self.name + '/' + str(self.id)
```

and in my resource

```
class TempResource(ModelResource) :
    modelNumber = fields.CharField(attribute='modelNumber', readonly=True)
    class Meta:
        queryset = Temp.objects.all()
        filtering = {'modelNumber':ALL}
```

I tried to make a request /temp/?modelNumber=NRA/1 . I am getting an error of Cannot resolve keyword 'modelNumber' into field .

Answer (score 0):

Could it be something related to the raw "/" in the url?